# Where to place django plugins

Tags: django

I'm starting my first Django project, and I'm required to download the first plugin for connecting to the database.

Where should this plugin be placed inside my django install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't.

You haven't really explained your question very well, but it seems like you're asking about the Python libraries to connect to MySQL or PostgresQL. These are not Django plugins, they're Python libraries. And they don't require 'placing' inside the Django install - they require installing on your machine. When you download one, it should include a setup script that will install itself as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the database drivers in the python environment for your django install.

You can use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to isolate python libraries from your base (system) python.

Answer (score 0):

You can store plugins folders in your project root directory